# How do i read out byte arrays in eclipse debugger?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

can you tell me how to show byte arrays (binary or hexadecimal) under the "variables" menu in eclipse debugging view?
For example:

> byte[] bytearray = {0x12};

Thank you very much for your help!

Chris

Comment: what do you mean by _show byte arrays_?  are you saying that the variable doesn't show up, or the value is unreadable?

Comment: the variable does not show up.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem.  I created a simple unit test and ran it in the debugger with this byte array: `byte[] b = "Hello, World!".getBytes();`, and it showed in the variables view without issue...

Comment: make loop, then show each one in log.d(TAG,byte[i].toString());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open the debug perspective on the top-right.

insert some break points.

when you run you code in debug mode, the program stops at the first point.

then you can find the variables in your memory(initialized).